# How to get image to display on php page using Wikipedia API

Tags: php, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, getimagedata

Hi i've got a php page that uses the wikipedia API using the zend framework to display results obtained from a search query. At the moment it displays the title of the article and a snippet of it. I would like to be able to display an image too. Please advise me further on this matter. Thanks.

Below is my code: (q is the value of whatever has been typed in the search box)

```
<?php
// if form submitted
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
    // load Zend classes
    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Rest_Client');
    try {
        // initialize REST client
        $wikipedia = new Zend_Rest_Client('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php');
        // set query parameters
        $wikipedia->action('query');
        $wikipedia->list('search');
        $wikipedia->srwhat('text');
        $wikipedia->format('xml');
        $wikipedia->srsearch($_POST['q']);
        // perform request
        // iterate over XML result set
        $result = $wikipedia->get();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
 ?>

 <h2>Search results for '<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>'</h2>
    <ol>
<?php foreach ($result->query->search->p as $r): ?>
<li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/
<?php echo $r['title']; ?>">
<?php echo $r['title']; ?></a> <br/>
<small><?php echo $r['snippet']; ?></small></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Format you code please ... including removing those unneeded blank lines

Comment: apologies for the poor formatting I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: What kind of image do you want to display? The first image on the page? Or a screenshot of the rendered page? Or the image behind a `File:` page? Or something else?

Comment: The first image on the page. Atm I get about 10 links displaying, I would like the first image of the page to display alongside the title and the snippet.

Comment: @svick on second thoughts if you know how to get a screenshot of the rendered page would it be possible to display those instead of the snippet? I want to create a page that involves less reading of text and quicker identification using visuals. so the user can just click on the title after looking at the screenshot and be directed to the wikipage.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any really good way AFAIK. You can get the generated HTML, find the first image which has reasonable size and display it (once you know the image name, you can use [the imageinfo API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#imageinfo_.2F_ii) to get an URL you can use in your own image tag).

Answer (score 0):

There is also the opportunity to consume Wikipedia pages through a wrapper API like [JSONpedia](http://jsonpedia.org/), it works both live (ask for the current JSON representation of a Wiki page) and storage based (query multiple pages previously ingested in Elasticsearch and MongoDB).

In particular JSONpedia provides an HTML view with renders to HTML the JSON extracted for a page.

For example this query processes the en:Albert_Einstein wiki page, extracts JSON and render it to basic HTML with fully resolved multimedia URIs.

http://jsonpedia.org/annotate/resource/html/en%3AAlbert_Einstein?&procs=Extractors#references